# How to set "auto insert" foreign key value by using SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key

I have created two tables and also created a relationship between them.

Table `students`:

```
create table students
(
    [StudentId] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    [Name] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL
);
```

Table `studentprofile`:

```
create table studentprofile
(
    [Id] INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1, 1),
    [StudentId] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    [Address] NVARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
);
```

and relationship:

```
alter table studentprofile
add constraint students_studentprofile_FK 
    foreign key (StudentId) 
    references students(StudentId) 
        on delete cascade on update cascade
```

But, when I wrote this line:

```
insert into students values('110111', 'Marik')
```

the value of `StudentId` (in table `studentprofile`) wasn't updated automatically. Why?

Can you tell me how to set the value of `StudentId` (in table `studentprofile`) can be inserted automatically whenever I insert into table `students`?

Comment: why would `inserting` have any impact on an `update cascade`?  `insert != update`

Comment: You should make 2 inserts. The first insert into `students` does not have the `Address` information for the `studentprofile` table.

Comment: additionally, what exactly are you hoping will be inserted into student profile?  It looks like a 1 to many relationship between the two tables so you would be able to insert an infinite number of rows, how are you to decide what should be inserted into the table automatically?  Especially when the columns are not nullable

Answer (score 6):

There is no such thing as `insert cascade`.
You can implement such a thing by using a trigger for insert on your `students` table, inserting default values (or nulls) into the `studentprofile` table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER students_insert ON students AFTER INSERT
AS
    INSERT INTO studentprofile(StudentId, Address)
    SELECT StudentId, 'NO ADDRESS'
    FROM inserted
```

Note that your Address column is defined as not null and has no default value, this is why I've used the hard coded `'NO ADDRESS'` for it.

However, I agree with the comments on your question: you would be better off inserting the data to the student profile using a different insert statement (perhaps inside a transaction with the insert to students).