# I need extract the data inserted into a table into two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need extract the data inserted into a table and extract the data inserted into last table and insert into another table table

```
create table tab1 (id bigint identity(1,1), col_1 varchar(4))
create table tab2 (id bigint identity(1,1), col_1 varchar(4), id_tab1 bigint)
create table tab3 (id bigint identity(1,1), col_1 varchar(4), id_tab2 bigint)
create table tab4 (id bigint identity(1,1), col_1 varchar(4), id_tab3 bigint)

insert into tab1 (col_1)
values ('AAAA'),('BBBB'),('CCCC')

insert into tab2 (col_1, id_tab1)
output inserted.col_1, inserted.id into tab3 (col_1, id_tab2)
--I NEED DO: OUTPUT FROM TAB3 INTO TAB4
output inserted.tab3.col_1, inserted.tab3.id into tab4 (col_1, id_tab3)
select col_1, id
from tab1
```

Comment: Is this what you need ? https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e05e4d07e1de4dd1d0924daa2d698316

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `output` clause requires an explicit `INSERT`.  So, use temporary tables:

```
declare @t2ids table (col_1 varchar(4), id_tab2 int);

insert into tab2 (col_1, id_tab1)
    output inserted.col_1, inserted.id into @t2ids (col_1, id_tab2);

declare @t3ids (col1 varchar(4), id_tab3);

insert into tab3 (col1, id_tab2)
    output inserted.col_1, inserted.id into @t3ids (col_1, id_tab3)
    select col_1, id_tab2
    from @t2ids;

insert into tab4 (col_1, id_tab3)
    select col_1, id_tab3
    from @t3ids;
```

Comment: I know I can do it this way, but I'd like to do everything in one

Comment: @VirtualCom . . . This answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be attempting to implement an ["insert cascade"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30847940/3094533) - meaning that an insert into the first table will automatically insert default values to the related table, and from that to the next related table and so on (up to tab4).
I would use triggers instead of the output clause for such a thing - create a trigger for insert on each table that will insert the relevant records to the next one:

```
create trigger trg_tab2_insert on tab2 for insert
as
insert into tab3(col_1, id_tab2)
select col_1, id
from inserted
```

and then

```
create trigger trg_tab3_insert on tab3 for insert
as
insert into tab4(col_1, id_tab3)
select col_1, id
from inserted
```

Please note that for this to work [nested trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/configure-the-nested-triggers-server-configuration-option?view=sql-server-ver15) should be enabled (Which is the default state in SQL Server)

Comment: I can't make a trigger

Answer (score 0):

Can you not run it as one script?

for instance script.sql:

```
insert into tab2 (col_1,id_tab1) select col_1,id from tab1
 insert into tab3 (col_1,id_tab2) select col_1,id from tab2
 insert into tab4 (col_1,id_tab3) select col_1,id from tab3
```

Comment: I would like to do all in one. For the moment I divided in two insert..